# Mobile Safari background when going to a new page, not white

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-applications, mobile-safari

I have two pages, both ones are black. When user clicks on a link to load the second page, Safari fills the client area with white, then shows the black page. It looks ugly. Any chance to set it up in a web-app meta or anywhere else?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad - but inevitable - solution is to make the pages white, if the browser detected as Mobile Safari.